# Should I add Floetrol / XIM Latex Extender to my Exterior Acrylic Latex Paint?

Tags: painting, paint, exterior

I painted my front door (metal) with Sherwin-Williams Emerald Exterior Satin (Acrylic Latex) and the result is not super. The paint dries so fast that I ended with multiple brush marks and roller marks. Because of panels on the doors, I have to use a brush and a roller.

After some online research, I found out about paint additive (e.g. Floetrol, XIM Latex Extender). According to what I read online (mostly online reviews...), those additive help getting rid of the brush and roller marks and makes it easier to apply.

https://www.lowes.com/pd/Flood-Floetrol-Interior-Exterior-Paint-Conditioner-Actual-Net-Contents-32-fl-oz/3376244

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Flood-Floetrol-1-qt-Clear-Latex-Paint-Additive-FLD6-04/100198078

Have you ever tried to add Floetrol / XIM Latex Extender to your paint? Does it really help? If it helps so much, why Sherwin Williams does not add it to its paints? Thanks!

Comment: I usually will use floetroll on cabinets where I want a smooth high sheen it helps. I find removing the doors and painting them horizontal provides the best results.

Comment: If you're using it on a door with panels it tends to drip at the corners of the panels where paint builds up. It does not dry as quickly so you can go back and touch up the drips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules that **I** live by for painting doors:

- always paint in the shade, and not when it is too hot (>75°F)
- always remove doors and lay flat for painting
- always brush doors, no rollers (unless "back-rolling" after brushing, for texture)
- do not skimp on paint when applying
- always maintain a "wet edge"
- **always use professional grade brushes**- emphasis intentional, this makes all the difference

You purchased top grade paint, there should be no need for additives at all.

Comment: I use floetrol even when spraying it helps to get a high sheen noticeably better in my opinion,  I do agree with quality brushes, if you are doing a job and it is 90+  you can't wait until winter in the shade and floetroll allows the paint to its best even on hot days as long as the paint is not over worked.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you? What's the weather like?

Cold days are good days to paint, cold damp rainy days are even better!

Good job I live in the UK

Seriously - may be better to paint winter time or when it's coolest, you'll have a wet edge for longer and get a better result

I used floetrol to spray interior matt emulsion and had good results with it, less blockage, longer wet time

Comment: I am in the US. Pacific Northwest.

Answer (score 0):

I have had zero luck with Flotroel, but have had better luck with Original Seal-Krete, an acrylic base sealer for concrete floors, etc. Looks about the same as Flotroel but thinner.  I have used it to thin Acrylic house paint with great success.  Works summer or winter.  I used Flotroel here in Florida in hot September.  Just does not flow out so brush marks are little improved.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This isn't a discussion forum, so I've edited out some of your commentary. Please check out our help pages to see how to better contribute, and hope to see more from you!